How to prevent the default hover effect in NavigationMenuTrigger in vue.js?
I am new to using vue.js
I'm using this component   <NavigationMenuTrigger/> from 'radix-vue'
basically when i hover on the menu it triggers and open it.. and when it's opened if i hover outside it closes it.
I want to disable both the trigger on hover the click outside/ hover outside.
i tried this
const disabled = true;


const forwardedProps = useForwardProps(delegatedProps)
</script>

<template>
  <NavigationMenuTrigger
  :disableHoverTrigger = "disabled"
  :disableOutsidePointerEvents = "disabled"


    v-bind="forwardedProps"
    :class="cn(navigationMenuTriggerStyle(), 'group', props.class)"
  >
    <slot />
    <ChevronDown
      class="relative top-px ml-1 h-3 w-3 transition duration-200 group-data-[state=open]:rotate-180"
      aria-hidden="true"
    />
  </NavigationMenuTrigger>
</template>

but for some reason, it doesn't work

disableHoverTrigger prop is meant to go on <NavigationMenuRoot> component.  That's what "Root" is in the API documentation. While it's not shown, you must have one somewhere, so simply add the prop to it.
FYI, boolean props when added to a component are assumed ="true" (source: Vue docs), so an example for what your Root component should look like would be:
<NavigationMenuRoot
  v-model="currentTrigger"
  class="relative z-[1] flex w-full justify-center"
  disableHoverTrigger
>

